# Vue.js referenced template components stop after first sub component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm attempting to create components using Vue, so that I can remove a lot of duplicated HTML in a site I'm working on.

I have a `<ym-menucontent>` component, which within it will eventually have several other components, conditionally rendered.

While doing this I've hit a wall and so have simplified everything to get to the root of the problem.

When rendering the `ym-menucontent` component the first sub-component is the only one which gets rendered and I can't work out why or how to get around it...

```
<template id="menucontent">
    <div>
        <ym-categories :menuitem="menuitem"/>
        <ym-rootmaps :menuitem="menuitem"/>
        <p>1: {{menuitem.rootMapsTab}}</p>
        <p>2: {{menuitem.exploreTab}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="rootmaps">
    <div>Root Maps</div>
</template>

<template id="categories">
    <div>Categories</div>
</template>
```

app.js

```
Vue.component('ym-menucontent', {
    template: '#menucontent',
    props: ['menuitem'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            customMenu: window.customMenuJSON
        }
    }
});
Vue.component('ym-rootmaps', {
    template: '#rootmaps',
    props: ['menuitem'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            customMenu: window.customMenuJSON,
            rootMaps: window.rootAreas
        }
    }
});
Vue.component('ym-categories', {
    template: '#categories',
    props: ['menuitem'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            customMenu: window.customMenuJSON,
            rootMaps: window.rootAreas
        }
    }
});
```

usage...

```
<div 
    v-for="mi in customMenu.topLevelMenuItems"
    :id="mi.name" 
    class="page-content tab swiper-slide">
         <ym-menucontent :menuitem="mi"/>
</div>
```

Output

```
<div>Categories</div>
```

if I switch around `ym-cateogries` and `ym-rootmaps` then the output becomes...

```
<div>Root Maps</div>
```

if I remove both then I see...

```
<p>1: true</p>
<p>2:</p>
```

I'd expect to see a combination of all of them...

```
<div>Categories</div>
<div>Root Maps</div>
<p>1: true</p>
<p>2:</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you're using  self-closing components in DOM templates, which is recommended against in the [style-guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended) ..

> Unfortunately, HTML doesn’t allow custom elements to be self-closing -
> only [official “void” elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#void-elements). That’s why the strategy is only
> possible when Vue’s template compiler can reach the template before
> the DOM, then serve the DOM spec-compliant HTML.

This should work for you ..

```
<template id="menucontent">
    <div>
        <ym-categories :menuitem="menuitem"></ym-categories>
        <ym-rootmaps :menuitem="menuitem"></ym-rootmaps>
        <p>1: {{menuitem.rootMapsTab}}</p>
        <p>2: {{menuitem.exploreTab}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

---

```
<div 
    v-for="mi in customMenu.topLevelMenuItems"
    :id="mi.name" 
    class="page-content tab swiper-slide">
         <ym-menucontent :menuitem="mi"></ym-menucontent>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect... Solves my issue and explains why it happens... A+++, would stack again...

Comment: @Matt Glad to help. Cheers :)